# Function not declared in scope

Tags: scope, header, declaration

Whenever I try to compile my code I get an error:

> ```
> UBVector.cpp: In function ‘int UBVector::* insert(int*, int)’:
> UBVector.cpp:95:33: error: ‘reserve’ was not declared in this scope
>        reserve(2*current_capacity);
> ```

I'm compiling using `g++ driver.cpp UBVector.cpp`

I cannot figure out why this is happening and any help would be appreciated! Thanks

## **UBVector.h**

```
#ifndef _UBVECTOR_H
#define _UBVECTOR_H

#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;


class UBVector{
public:
   void swap(UBVector& x);
   void reserve(size_t n);
   //constructors and assignment operator
   UBVector(const UBVector &x);  //copy constuctor
   explicit UBVector(size_t n=0, int val=0);
   UBVector(int *pBegin, int *pEnd);
   UBVector& operator = (const UBVector &x);
   //deconstructor
   ~UBVector();
   //capacity
   size_t size() const;
   size_t capacity() const;
   //
   int *begin();
   int *end();
   //modifiers
   int *insert(int *pPosition, const int val);
   int *erase(int *pPosition);
   void push_back(const int &val);
   void pop_back();
   //accessors
   int& at(size_t n);
   int& operator[](size_t n);
   int& front();
   int& back();
   //

private:
   size_t num_items; //number of items currently in array
   size_t current_capacity; //current capacity of array
   static const size_t INITIAL_CAPACITY; //initial capacity of array
   int *item_ptr; //points to start of array
};

#endif
```

## **UBVector.cpp**

```
#include "UBVector.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const size_t UBVector::INITIAL_CAPACITY = 5; //allocate array space and size
size_t num_items = 0;
size_t current_capacity = 0;
int *item_ptr;
//constructor that creates an array of size n and sets each element to a variable val
UBVector::UBVector(size_t n, int val){  
   num_items = n;
   current_capacity = max(n, INITIAL_CAPACITY);
   item_ptr = new int[current_capacity];
   for(int i=0; i<current_capacity; i++){
      item_ptr[i] = val;
   }
}

UBVector::UBVector(const UBVector& x)
   : num_items(x.num_items), current_capacity(x.num_items), item_ptr(new int[x.num_items])
{  
   for(size_t i=0; i<num_items; i++){
      item_ptr[i] = x.item_ptr[i];
   }
}

UBVector::UBVector(int *pBegin, int *pEnd){
   num_items = *pEnd - *pBegin;
   current_capacity = num_items;
   item_ptr = new int[current_capacity];
   for(int i=*pBegin; i<=*pEnd; i++){
      item_ptr[i] = i;
   }
}

UBVector::~UBVector(){
   delete [] item_ptr;
}

void UBVector::swap(UBVector& x){
   std::swap(num_items, x.num_items);
   std::swap(current_capacity, x.current_capacity);
   std::swap(item_ptr, x.item_ptr);
}

UBVector& UBVector::operator= (const UBVector& x){
   UBVector temp(x);
   swap(temp);
   return *this;
}

//returns current size of the vector(number of elements)
size_t UBVector::size() const{
   return num_items;
}

//returns the current capacity of the vector
size_t UBVector::capacity() const{
   return current_capacity;
}

//returns pointer to first element in vector
int* UBVector::begin(){
   int x = item_ptr[0];
   int *pX = &x;
   return pX;
}

//returns pointer to last element in vector
int* UBVector::end(){
   int x = item_ptr[num_items];
   int *pX = &x;
   return pX;
}

//checks if array is full, if it is then it creates a new array with 2x the previous capacity(or n, whichever is larger) and copies all the data from the previous array
void UBVector::reserve(size_t n){
   if(n > current_capacity){
      current_capacity = max(n, 2*current_capacity);
      int *new_data_ptr = new int[current_capacity];
      for(size_t i=0; i<num_items; i++){
         new_data_ptr[i] = item_ptr[i];
      }
      delete [] item_ptr;
      item_ptr = new_data_ptr;
   }
}

//inserts element into vector before the element at pPosition, if array is full array size is the increased 
int UBVector::*insert(int *pPosition, const int val){
   if(num_items == current_capacity){
      reserve(2*current_capacity);
   }
   for(size_t i=num_items; i>*pPosition; --i){
      item_ptr[i] = item_ptr[i-1];
   }
   item_ptr[*pPosition] = val;
   ++num_items;
}

//removes element at pPosition from vector, shifts all elements over and empties last element in vector
int UBVector::*erase(int *pPosition){
   if(*pPosition < num_items){
      for(size_t i=*pPosition; i<num_items-1; ++i){
         item_ptr[i] = item_ptr[i+1];
      }
      item_ptr[num_items-1] = int();
      num_items--;
   }
}

//adds element to the end of the vector if array is not full, if it is then a larger array will be created using the reserve method
void UBVector::push_back(const int& val){
   if(num_items == current_capacity){
      reserve(2*current_capacity);
   }
   item_ptr[num_items++] = val;
}

//erases last element in vector
void UBVector::pop_back(){
   int x = num_items-1;
   int *pX = &x;
   erase(pX);
}

//returns reference to element at n in vector
int& UBVector::at(size_t n){
   return item_ptr[n];
}

//returns reference to element at n, if n is larger than than the number of items in the vector, an out of range exception is thrown
int& UBVector::operator[](size_t n){
   if(n < num_items){
      return item_ptr[n];
   }
   else{
      throw out_of_range("index is out of range");
   }
}

//returns reference to first element in vector
int& UBVector::front(){
   return (*this)[0];
}

//returns referece to last element in vector
int& UBVector::back(){
   return (*this)[num_items-1];
}
```

## **Driver.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "UBVector.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
   UBVector ubv(3);
   ubv[0] = 5; ubv[1] = 6; ubv[2] = 7;

   cout << ubv[0] << ubv[1] << ubv[2] << endl;

   ubv.front() = 85;
   ubv.back() = 95;
   cout << ubv.front() << ubv.back() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is from your wrong syntax.

int *insert(int *, const int) is a function that returns 'int *' with name 'insert', not a function that returns 'int' with name '* insert'.

Therefore, you need to include 'insert' to your class's namespace, not '* insert'.

As code,

```
//inserts element into vector before the element at pPosition, if array is full array size is the increased 
int *UBVector::insert(int *pPosition, const int val){
   if(num_items == current_capacity){
      reserve(2*current_capacity);
   }
   for(size_t i=num_items; i>*pPosition; --i){
      item_ptr[i] = item_ptr[i-1];
   }
   item_ptr[*pPosition] = val;
   ++num_items;
}

//removes element at pPosition from vector, shifts all elements over and empties last element in vector
int *UBVector::erase(int *pPosition){
   if(*pPosition < num_items){
      for(size_t i=*pPosition; i<num_items-1; ++i){
         item_ptr[i] = item_ptr[i+1];
      }
      item_ptr[num_items-1] = int();
      num_items--;
   }
}
```

In other functions, you use right syntax, so, as I think, it's just a mistake, isn't it?